# Calling "npm run generate" from PHP file results in "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"

Tags: php, node.js, npm, webpack, nuxtjs

I'm calling `npm run generate` from PHP to generate static sites from NuxtJS. Running the below code results in ***Return Code: 254 - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE***.

```
<?php
exec("export PATH=/www/htdocs/w01234567/nodejs/bin && npm run generate 2>&1", $out, $result);
echo "ReturnCode: " .$result ."<br>";
echo "Output: " ."<br>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($out);
?>
```

The `generate.php` file is in the same folder as all NuxtJS files. *`(https://example.com/12345/generate.php)`*

If I call `npm run generate` through SSH (via PuTTY) it works though.

What I'be tried so far:

- Update/reinstall all node_modules
- Update/reinstall nodejs/npm

How to fix this error?

Edit: Full error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/www/htdocs/w12345678/nodejs/bin/npm', 'run', 'generate' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v15.4.0
4 verbose node symlink /www/htdocs/w12345678/nodejs/bin/node
5 verbose run-script [ 'pregenerate', 'generate', 'postgenerate' ]
6 info lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~pregenerate: new-blog@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: new-blog@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: PATH: /www/htdocs/w12345678/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/www/htdocs/w12345678/example.com/abcdefgh123456789/node_modules/.bin:/www/htdocs/w12345678/nodejs/bin
10 verbose lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: CWD: /www/htdocs/w12345678/example.com/abcdefgh123456789
11 silly lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: Args: [ '-c', 'nuxt generate' ]
12 info lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: Failed to exec generate script
13 silly lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: Returned: code: -2  signal: null
14 info lifecycle new-blog@1.0.0~generate: Failed to exec generate script
15 verbose stack Error: new-blog@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
15 verbose stack spawn sh ENOENT
15 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:276:19)
15 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
15 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
16 verbose pkgid new-blog@1.0.0
17 verbose cwd /www/htdocs/w12345678/example.com/abcdefgh123456789
18 verbose Linux 4.15.0-129-generic
19 verbose argv "node" "/www/htdocs/w12345678/nodejs/bin/npm" "run" "generate"
20 verbose node v15.4.0
21 verbose npm  v6.14.10
22 error code ELIFECYCLE
23 error syscall spawn sh
24 error file sh
25 error path sh
26 error errno -2
27 error new-blog@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
27 error spawn sh ENOENT
28 error Failed at the new-blog@1.0.0 generate script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Comment: check permissions

Comment: Can you please explain for which folder or file? Thank you

Comment: Do you have the full output of the error? ELIFECYCLE always points to an further error in a lifecycle script (in this case `generate`), and there should be a log file mentioned in the output that may or may not have more detail. You could also try manually adding `npm bin` to path as well (`node_modules/.bin`).

Comment: @ZacAnger Thanks for your answer. Just added the full error log to my question. Does it help pin down the issue?

Comment: Yes: I believe the real issue is the `spawn sh ENOENT` line, which points to PATH being an issue, and on a closer look it is: `export PATH=/www/htdocs/w01234567/nodejs/bin` should be `export PATH=/www/htdocs/w01234567/nodejs/bin:$PATH` — you're overwriting all of `PATH`. NPM scripts call `sh -c [the stuff in the script]` which is where it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-export PATH=/www/htdocs/w01234567/nodejs/bin
+export PATH=/www/htdocs/w01234567/nodejs/bin:$PATH
```

You're overwriting `PATH` entirely rather than prepending to it, so npm scripts aren't able to run, because npm shells out.

EDIT:

In the chat, we discovered that PATH didn't exist at all in the PHP script, so rebuilt it manually: `export PATH=/www/htdocs/w123456/nodejs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin && npm run generate 2>&1"`. Why PATH isn't accessible in the PHP script we don't know, but building it manually from the common paths works.

Comment: Just tried `export PATH=/www/htdocs/w01234567/nodejs/bin:$PATH` but got the same error. Can I run any script to verify the correct PATH or something like that?

Comment: Darn, I was positive that was it. Do you have a moment to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227097/zacanger-and-tom To check your `PATH`, you can have it run `echo $PATH` after setting it. You can also doublecheck what you have available with `which sh`, `which bash`, and `which nuxt`, which could clarify things (in the PHP script, since that's where PATH is getting changed).

Comment: I'm in the the chat  now